# prolog list keeps expanding when semi colon is pressed

Tags: prolog

Hi I am creating a predicate list from, which if used gives you the numbers between a certain range. So say for instance

```
list_from(1,5,X).
```

would give you

```
X=[1,2,3,4,5].
```

However I got my predicate to work, but the list just keeps expanding, so it keeps increasing my one and I do not want it to. This is what is happening.

```
?- list_from(1,7,X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...]
```

How do I get this to stop?

Here is my code

```
list_from(M,N,[]):- M > N.
list_from(M,N,[M|T]):- Mplusone is M + 1, list_from(Mplusone,N,T).
```

if I remove Mplusone and just M instead I get an error "Out of global stack"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two clauses are not mutually exclusive. You have a "guard" in the first clause saying that `M > N`, but you don't have the opposite condition, `M =< N`, in the second clause. If you trace the execution you should get an idea of what happens with your current definition.

You might also try to look at the [definition of `numlist/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#numlist/3) in SWI-Prolog's `library(lists)`. It takes a different approach: first, make sure that the arguments make sense; then, under the condition that the initial `Low` is indeed lower than `High` (and both are integers), generate a list.

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon means that you want Prolog to show you more options (that you are not satisfied with the answer). A full stop '.' will stop Prolog from providing you with alternatives.

You could also invoke list_from/3 using once/1. (Credit to @mat)

Comment: That's not a good solution: If you query `?- list_from(4, 1, Ls).` then it gives you as the *single* solution: `Ls = []`. But if you query `?- list_from(4, 1, [4]).` it succeeds *too*. So which is it: Is `Ls = [4]` now a solution or not? If you really want to commit to the first solution, use `once/1` when you *invoke* the predicate.